# Probability of player winning

Tags: probability

In a game Player 1 goes first and has a probability of 1/2 of winning in a given turn. Player 2 goes second and has a probability of 15/16 of winning in a given turn. I believe that the probability that player to wins in a given round(1 turn for each player) of the game is 15/32, but don't know how to figure out the probability that player 2 wins the whole game

Don't want to post my logic for getting to that point. Assuming what I have is right I don't know how to tie it together for a final answer

Comment: Have you heard of Markov Chains?  You may approach this either via matrices or tree diagrams (although the tree will be fractal)(or simply a probability argument without needing to visualize the diagram).  I personally prefer the use of matrices as that gives additional information without any extra work in the way of not only who wins in the long term with what probability, but also how many turns it takes on average.

Comment: One way: $(1/2)(3/4)+(1/2)(1/4)(1/2)(3/4)+(1/2)(1/4)(1/2)(1/4)(1/2)(3/4)+\cdots$: infinite geometric series.

Comment: If "player to" is a typo for "player two" your calculation is incorrect.  The chance that player two wins in a given round is $1/2$ (that player one doesn't win) times $3/4$ (that player two wins given the chance) $=3/8$

Comment: @TheGodPat Since your edit with the different probabilities, the method used in the answers below still applies, though it will clearly change the exact answers in the outcome.  For the series summation like my first treediagram or Andre's comment, simply calculate the probability player 2 wins on her $n^{th}$ turn by multiplying by the probabilities of each branch to get to the $n^{th}$ leaf (in particular player1 misses $n$ times and player 2 misses $n-1$ times and then wins one time).

Comment: @TheGodPat To use the collapsed tree diagram argument like paw and my second answer, it is going to be $\frac{p_2}{p_1+(1-p_1)p_2}$ where $p_1$ is probability player 1 wins during his turn and $p_2$ is the probability that player 2 wins during her turn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two versions of the tree diagram for what is going on.

[image]

From looking at the top diagram, you can conclude the probability that player 2 wins on her first/second/third/.../$n^{th}$ turns (i.e. arriving at each respective leaf) by multiplying by the probabilities along the branches.

So, for player 2 to win on her first turn, it occurs with probability $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{4} = \frac{3}{8}$  (player 1 first has to miss on his turn and then she has to win).  For player 2 to win on her second turn, it occurs with probability $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{4}=\frac{3}{64}$ (player1miss, player2miss, player1miss, player2 win).  In general, you see that player2 will win on her $n^{th}$ turn with probability $(\frac{1}{8})^{n-1}\frac{3}{8}$.

By adding up all of the different cases, we get the probability that she wins overall (regardless of turn) $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{8})^{n-1}\frac{3}{8} = \frac{3}{8}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{8}} = \frac{3}{8}\cdot\frac{1}{\frac{7}{8}} = \frac{3}{7}$, a geometric series which you should be familiar with.

A perhaps more intuitive way to look at this however with much a much easier time calculating, is the second tree diagram.  By collapsing the tree to look at each *round* as a whole, as player 1 beings the round he continues to have a 1/2 chance of winning, player2 now has a 3/8 chance of winning the round (as she has to wait for her turn to begin), and there is a 1/8 chance that the process repeats itself.  By noting that the next branching point looks precisely the same as the previous one, you can convince yourself that she will win with probability $\frac{\frac{3}{8}}{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{8}} = \frac{3}{7}$.  No fancy series summation tricks needed.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine two people sharing a unit of water.  The first person takes $\frac12$ the water; the second person takes $\frac34$ of what's left, which is $\frac38$ of the original amount of water.  Currently the ratio of the first person's water to the second person's is $4:3$.

The first person takes $\frac12$ the remaining water, and the second person takes $\frac34$ of what is left.  Their total amounts of water are still in a ratio of $4:3$.

This goes on forever.  The ratio after each round is still $4:3$.

So the first person gets $\frac47$ of the original water; the second person gets $\frac37$.

Comment: I screwed up, player two had 15/16 probability, how does that change things?

Comment: With player two's chance increased to $15/16$, the water gets divided in the ratio $16:15$.